# IOS 7 javascript alert title change

Tags: ios

Can anyone suggest me how to *change title on javascript alert box,confirm box and prompt box* in IOS 7 `UIWebView` on tab click and submit button click?

Answer (score 0):

These are regulations from Javascript, and it is not possible to change this when you are using a standard alert/confirm message.

Try to use an alternative Javascript Popup (for Example Bootstrap Modal) where you can define everything you need.

Comment: Thanks...but will u please tell me the lighter js alert to use it in my code?

Comment: This is not a "Please show me how it works" Platform. Try yourself and if you have any questions or problems, then u can ask. Read the "How should i ask" first. Good Luck